# Stacks in C++. Why and when are they used?

Tags: c++, stack

After reading a chapter on stacks (Chapter 7, Data Structures using C++. 2nd Edition, D.S. Malik). I seem to have troubles grasping the concept of using a stack in C++.

I understand that a stack itself, is a data type, and is used primarily in a LIFO (Last in first out) programming style. There are functions that the stack can offer for use... such as `pop`, `push`, `isEmpty`, `isFull`, and `top` but I don't quite understand what each one does fully and how they work together.

What are they used for in the 'big picture?' How can I think when a stack would be useful while writing code?

Any explanation or examples would be very helpful!

Thank you,

Comment: You mean, why a LIFO data structure is useful?

Comment: Are you trying to understand how to implement a stack in C++? Or do you want to know what a stack is useful for in general? If you mean the general question, this is not a C++ question.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to understand how to implement a stack in C++ @David K

Comment: Start with an array.  Think about what state information the stack needs to know in order to do each of the functions you listed.  Think about what those values equal before a call to push, and after a call to push.  Think about which element is the top.  Start with a whiteboard and work through some examples.

Answer (score 2):

Stacks are used in a wide range of algorithms.  Some example:

- translating recursive algorithms in an iterative equivalent
- parralelizing recursive algorithms (required a thread-safe stack implementation)
- implement a depth first graph search, when the same algorithm with a queue will give you a breath first.
- executing a postfix expression
- etc...

About the general principle of stacks:

- at beginining, the stack is empty. It's generally needed to check if a stack is **empty**, to know if htere are further elements to process.
- fixed size implementation of stacks need to check if space remains free before trying to store new elements.
- **push** puts a new element on the top of the stack thus increasing the number of elements.
- **pop** takes the element from the top of the stack (i.e. the last one that was pushed) and decreases the stack.
- **top** reads the top element of the stack but leave it where it is without modifying the stack.

Remark about top and pop:  In traditional stacks (ex:  assembler of your CPU), pop reads the top of the stack AND removes it.  But many implementations separate the two operation in top (reading the top element) and pop (removing the top element).

I'd recommend that you get familiar with [`std::stack`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/) which is slightly different from your book (at least for the naming of the operation) but is immediatly available.

Answer (score 2):

I just checked my codebase, and the only places that I use a stack-like data structure are:

1. when lexing stage of parsing scripts, to match the positions of parentheses, solely for better error messages.
2. during the evaluation of scripts, so that I can save the "environment" if I need to return before the script is done (i.e. during a "sleep" call, so that other code can still run).

It is much more common for me to use recursive calls (i.e. the hardware stack), or to instead want a set or queue.

Comment: Yes, recursion is vey nice ! But unfortunately, hardware stack is  limited in size on  some environments.  Also, the optimizer can perform a much better job on loops (f.ex. finding loop invariants) than on recursive calls.

Comment: @Christophe I don't believe in teaching usually-bad habit just because there are *some* systems out there with extremely small stacks. And my experience is that recursion is easier to optimize, because it's more likely to have be functional (i.e. have immutable variables).

Comment: Many years ago, it used to be that the fixed overhead of a function call was so large, and compilers optimized so poorly, that you could speed up some deep recursions greatly by implementing your own stack instead of using the call stack. This seems to be much less often true nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of specific situations where you might want to use a stack. The ones that come to mind are

1. Convert a "normal" infix mathematical expression to a postfix or prefix expression.
2. Evaluate a mathematical expression.
3. Traversing a maze.

Comment: and many others. Check: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)

Answer (score 0):

I use a stack in my compiler to track local variables and types in each "scope" - since it's a Pascal compiler, it allows nested functions and with that a new set of variables and types at each nesting level. So, I have a stack, which starts with global variables, and then for each level of function, I add another level of stack. When the function is "complete", the stack is "popped" to remove that layer.

Stacks are used for many other things of that sort of nature, in other words, you have something with layers. You can break down a mathematical expression:

```
 x = a + b * (d - e);
```

So, we find `x =`, and look at what's next: It's not just a single variabe so we have to break it into parts:

```
 a + b,
```

but next is `*`, which has a higher priority than `+`, so we need to push what `a`, `+` and `b` we have so far onto the stack, and first calculate * something. Which is in parenthesis, so we have to push the `*` too, and calculate `d - e`. Now we can start walking back towards the bottom of the stack: `pop` gives us `*` and then `b`, so multiply those together, and then pop next, which gives `+` and `a`. Finally we get `=` and `x`, so we do the assignment. (Although in my compiler project, I simply solve this by calling the binary operator parser from within the binary operator parser).

Many games that "try different options" (Sudoku solver, Chess, Tic-Tac-Toe, Maze finding etc) use recursion or a stack to track "what options do we have", where each further move is another layer on the stack. Again, it can either be done in regular recursion, or using a stack. Simply enumerate the possible "moves" at this point, pick one and make that move, then do the same for the oponent [assuming it's a two-way game, rather than Sudoku or maze], and so on. Each "played step" is a stack level. If you find a "good" one, traverse back after storing "this is the right move" - if it went badly, then traverse back with "not a good move" [in chess and for example, many moves may be "good" (because there are several options, or because there are so many choices that we can't try every one all the way to "win/lose" situation) and a few "bad", so you then have to score moves on "how good" it is].

There are lots of other things where "I need to remember where I was before, so that I can get back to it later".

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** In my original answer I foolishly overlooked the already existing STL
stack implementation, `std::stack`.  This has `push`, `pop`, and `top` functions
that do exactly what you'd expect, and an `empty` function that implements the
desired `isEmpty()` function.

For example, to make `my_stack_instance` be a stack of integers you can simply 
declare

```
std::stack<int> my_stack_instance;
```

There is no "isFull" operation per se. The `std::stack` is supposed to "grow"
(reallocate itself in a larger block of memory) if you exceed its capacity.

My previous suggestion was to use `std::vector`. Ideally it wouldn't *be* your
stack object, it would be *in* your stack object so that you can expose functions
using names that make sense and not expose functions that you don't want.
If you use `std::stack` then it might as well *be* your stack object since it
already exposes exactly the functions it should.

If you have to implement a stack in order to prove you understand it for a class,
then `std::stack` probably wouldn't be accepted. I would then have a bone to pick
with your instructor regarding the use of C++ as a "teaching" language, but
that's a different topic, I suppose.